# Alterar valor por texto

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber se é possível trocar o valor das somas imput por texto. Ex: se o resultado for maior que 100, troca-se o valor por um texto.

Ex: Se o resultado for maior que 100 = BOM

```html
<html>
   <body>
<script> 
function soma() 
{
form.campo4.value = (form.campo1.value*1) + (form.campo2.value*1) + (form.campo3.value*1)
}

</script>
<form name="form">
<input name="campo1"><br> 
<input name="campo2"><br> 
<input name="campo3"><br> 
<input name="campo4" readonly><br>
<input type="button" onclick="soma()" value="Soma os Valores">
</form>
   </body>
</html>
```

se puder deixar como ficaria o código já alterado eu agradeceria :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma:

```js
function soma(){
   var resultado = +form.campo1.value + +form.campo2.value/2 + +form.campo3.value;
   var texto = 'RUIM';
   if(resultado > 100){
      texto = "BOM";
   }
   form.campo4.value = texto;
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
   <input name="campo1"><br> 
   <input name="campo2"><br> 
   <input name="campo3"><br> 
   <input name="campo4" readonly><br>
   <input type="button" onclick="soma()" value="Soma os Valores">
</form>
```

Não precisa multiplicar os valores por `1` para poder converter em número. Basta adicionar um `+` antes que já vira número.

Veja que coloquei um texto padrão `RUIM` e se o resultado for maior que 100, esse texto vira `BOM`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!